# How to complete quest "cold shoulder"?

Tags: borderlands-2

Somewhere during the play through, the quest "cold shoulder" will be given to you by scooter. At a certain point during the mission, there is a quest that requires you to find 5 slices of pizza in a specific area. However, I am unable to find the 5th slice of pizza even after I have scourged the area over and over again. I suppose this is due to the fact that the last slice of pizza did not load properly.

Thus, I would like to know how I could reload this piece of pizza so that I can retrieve it. It would also be useful if you could attach a few pictures of the specific locations of the 5 slices of pizza.

Comment: One of the slides is up high on a pile of cars? or some other metal junk, in the immediate vicinity of the other slices. Can't get screenshots at the moment, but I bet that's the one you're looking for.

Comment: Usually items and enemies in Borderlands respawn after leaving the area. But i doubt it's not loaded. Continue the search, it's probably somewhere on top of something :D

Comment: @BenBrocka o that one, I remember now :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I bet its the higher one (because that's the one I missed too :D), you can access it only by going back to the "main cave" (where you come from) then following the kind of road that ends up broken over the area where you were looking for the slices. When on the edge of the road's end look down and it should be on a rock below you.

You can watch [this video (at 10:38)](http://youtu.be/UPOzbKHcHZs?t=10m38s) that give you all the location

Comment: I see it cant believe I did not notice it before I was looking among the van and rubble